# 'Numbers only directive' not working in Chrome 49.xx.xx and below

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, input, angular-directive

I am using angular 6 and have written a directive to restrict the input to numbers only, for some of my input fields. The directive looks like this

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[NumbersOnly]'
})

export class NumbersOnlyDirective {
  // Allow decimal numbers and negative values
  private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*){0,1}$/g);
  // Allow key codes for special events. Reflect :
  // Backspace, tab, end, home
  private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight', 'Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home'];

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    // Allow Backspace, tab, end, and home keys
    if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
      return;
    }
    const current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    const next: string = current.concat(event.key);
    if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

and where ever I have my input fields, I use the directive as below

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="sendLinkMobile" NumbersOnly type="text" id="mobile-num"  
class="form-control m-no" placeholder="Mobile Number"  requried  minlength="10" 
maxlength="10" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
```

The code works perfectly in all the latest browsers, mobiles, tabs. But, when using it on chrome 49.xx and below, the input fields are not taking any values. Can anyone help me where the issue is?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it directive and check it out. I think Its work on chrome 49.xx

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[OnlyNumber]'
})
export class Onlynumber {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @Input() OnlyNumber: boolean;

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) {
    let e = <KeyboardEvent> event;
    if (this.OnlyNumber) {
      if ([46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+C
        (e.keyCode === 67 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+V
        (e.keyCode === 86 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+X
        (e.keyCode === 88 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
        // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
          // let it happen, don't do anything
          return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
      }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input OnlyNumber="true"  type="text" #numberModel="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="numberModel"  name="numberModel" />
```

Comment: It works fine, but when i am pasting any alphabet, its taking that as well. It should not allow pasting anything also.

Comment: Got exactly what i needed. Thanks

Comment: This is not working for mobile device, what to do?

Comment: @Hope you can use `ngx-mask'`package